# Start line chart's y-axis bars from the bottom even if that area is negative (ios charts)

Tags: ios, ios-charts

Maybe it's not the best title, but here is the explanation with images:

- This is what I currently have:
  [image]
- This is what I want:
  [image]

Sorry for the bad mock, but you get the idea.

All the values that are negative, the "bars" that are starting from 0 downwards, I want them to start from the bottom upwards.

Upon reading the docs I think I have to set the `leftAxis.axisMinValue`, but it doesn't affect the chart in any way.

```
// create dataSet (LineChartDataSet)

leftAxis.axisMinValue = dataSet.yMin

// create LineChartData and set to chart's data property
```

Maybe I'm missing something, it's not the right thing to set, or it's a bug. I did a bit of debugging and found that the `axisMinValue` is initially 0, and it gets set correctly to the passed value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out:

You need to set a custom `FillFormatter` on the dataSet (`dataSet.fillFormatter`)

```
class FillFormatter: ChartFillFormatter {
    func getFillLinePosition(dataSet dataSet: ILineChartDataSet, dataProvider: LineChartDataProvider) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(dataProvider.getAxis(.Left).axisMinValue)
    }
}
```